# Show loading icon before first react app initialization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, loading

What is the standard way of showing a loader icon before browser downloads all js files and loads react application.

Can I do something like this without breaking anything?

```
<div id="content" class="app">
  Loading...
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Once your javascript has loaded, you can replace `Loading...` by rendering your react app into the same `<div>`

```
render(
  <App />, 
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this using `component` life cycle methods.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: true
      };
    }
  
    componentWillMount(){
       this.setState({loading: true}); //optional 
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({loading: false}) 
    }
  
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="content">
              {this.state.loading && 'loading...'} {/*You can also use custom loader icon*/}
              <p>Your content comes here</p>
              {this.props.children}
            </section>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool but I wanted to show the icon before ReactDOM gets rendered. I am going to put my loader icon in #app div.

Comment: This will help when your `loading` component is again a `react` component. And this might be the better way than depending on html binding.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja what if you want to show a loading status to the client whilst they are downloading the assets on a slow network?