# Loading Div before render Page (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, components, lifecycle

I have an page but it's heavy, and react still spend some seconds to load all components, i would like to put an div with greater z-index to overlap it. The problem:

componentWillMount prints 'test' on console, but do not render the div:

```
componentWillMount() {
    return (
        <div className={this.props.classes.modalLoading}>
            TESTE
        </div>
    )
}
```

note css= 100vw, 100vh, bg: black, color: white

It's possible dismember in another component 'Loader' to use in another places? (console log don't work)

```
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
        <div className={classes.root} ref={'oi'}>
            <LayoutCard {...this.props}/>
        </div>
    )
}

componentDidMount() {
    {console.log('teste 3')}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that is not how react works :)
It renders the JSX that is returned from the `render()` method.. the return value of the `componentWillMount()` is not associated with the render method.

If you want a loader you should set a state on the main component to swap between a return, that returns a loader div and the return that returns your page content. I'm not sure what you mean by 'loading' in react. Maybe any sync ajax stuff? Set a state after it finished.

```
if(this.state.loaded) {
    return <Loader />
} else {
    return <Content />
}
```

If you mean things like fonts, stylesheets and images...
well thats its a duplicate of

[Show loading icon before first react app initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679912/show-loading-icon-before-first-react-app-initialization)

Comment: "to swap between a return, that returns a loader div and the return that returns your page content." i don't understand this part

Comment: adjusted my answer and added a code example... I took custom tags as example

Answer (score 0):

almost that, thx for the point @FelixGaebler

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        flag: true,
    })
}

render() {
    const { classes } = this.props
    if (this.state.flag) {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.classes.modalLoading}>
                <span>TEST</span>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <LayoutCard {...this.props}/>
        </div>
    )
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        flag: false,
    })
}
```